# How do I redirect to a corresponding route when user switches languages?

Tags: localization, routes

I'm working on a multilingual site with english and spanish locales. I've built persistent switcher that resides in the site footer. When users click it, it redirects to a corresponding entry in the other locale if one exists and the homepage if one does not.

The problem is that I have a handful of pages on my site that aren't entries: they are routes that are tied to particular templates. For example:

`news-events/tags`

Is the route for a template that lists all tags in use in my news section, and:

`noticias-eventos/tags`

would be the corresponding route on the spanish site.

I'd like to be able to check if the current uri is covered by a route and if so, whether there is a corresponding route in the other locale. If so, I'd redirect to that and if not, back to the homepage as per usual.

But from what I can see, routes are not localizable and exist independently of each other. Am I wrong? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather hacky workaround, but I have no idea what else you could do to handle it. What I do is to compose an array of "route objects" that basically mirror the routes set up in the CP. This array can then be compared to the URL segments (→ [`getSegments`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getSegments)). Not nice but it works :)

```
{# Map the corresponding routes #}
{% set routes = [
    { en: 'news-events/tags', es: 'noticias-eventos/tags' },
    { en: 'news-events/categories', es: 'noticias-eventos/categorias' },
] %}

{# Configure and loop through selected site locales #}
{% set locales = ['en', 'es'] %}
{% for locale in locales %}

    {# Is this an entry page? #}
    {% if entry is not defined %}

        {# ... Do entry stuff #}

    {# Not an entry page --> check the routes #}
    {% else %}

        {# Get URL segments #}
        {% set segments = craft.request.getSegments %}

        {# Set var before loop #}
        {% set noRoute = true %}

        {# Loop routes array #}
        {% for prop in routes %}

            {# Check if URL segments match a route #}
            {% if prop[craft.locale]|split('/') == segments %}

                {# Output link to the mapped route #}
                <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ prop[locale] }}">{{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name }}</a>

                {# Switch var value #}
                {% set noRoute = false %}

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        {# No route found --> output a link to the homepage #}
        {% if noRoute %}
            <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] }}">{{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name }}</a>
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To clean this up a bit you could try to use the containment operator `in` instead of the `for` loop. Not the first time I fail on getting it to work with objects. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, should be possible according to the [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response @carlcs. A great starting place.

Answer (score 2):

I need something like this and found a solution: [craft-languagelink](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-languagelink)

**UPDATE**: This solution does not work for what Adam needs.

Comment: Can you please share how to set up the plugin to link from `news-events/tags` to `noticias-eventos/tags` if the pages are no entry pages?

Comment: sorry, @carlcs I got it wrong, and also need something and it did not work.